# What is the behavior of request's response when used in an if condition?

Tags: python, python-requests

In Python, it seems that there is a difference in the `requests` library, and likely in other cases, where doing a conditional check on a class may not be truthy.

Here is a repository with two tests that demonstrate what seems to be a bug: https://github.com/vantaboard/minimal-reproduction-requests-bug

And here are the relevant snippets:

```py
except HTTPError as error:
    # This will not work as expected even if error.response is not None
    if error.response and error.response.status_code == 404:
        print("Not Found")
                                                                         
    # This does work, and I don't know why
    if error.response is not None and error.response.status_code == 404:
        print("Not Found")
```

I'm wondering if this means I need to do this explicitly instead of what I'm used to with other programming languages.

Comment: What do you mean by "work"?  What do you expect to happen, and what happens instead?

Comment: `bool(error.response)` returns `False`. looks pretty handy and not like a bug

Comment: Under what condition would you expect `error.response` to be `None`?  That doesn't seem like a case that could occur at all.

Answer (score 2):

The `error.response` attribute will be set to an instance of the `requests.models.Response` class, so it will never be `None`.

When you use `if error.response` as a truth test, [the default behavior](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) is defined as

> By default, an object is considered true unless its class defines either a `__bool__()` method that returns False or a `__len__()` method that returns zero, when called with the object.

Looking at the source code for `requests.models.Response`, we can see the following:

```py
class Response:
    """The :class:`Response <Response>` object, which contains a
    server's response to an HTTP request.
    """

    ...

    def __bool__(self):
        """Returns True if :attr:`status_code` is less than 400.

        This attribute checks if the status code of the response is between
        400 and 600 to see if there was a client error or a server error. If
        the status code, is between 200 and 400, this will return True. This
        is **not** a check to see if the response code is ``200 OK``.
        """
        return self.ok

    ...

    @property
    def ok(self):
        """Returns True if :attr:`status_code` is less than 400, False if not.

        This attribute checks if the status code of the response is between
        400 and 600 to see if there was a client error or a server error. If
        the status code is between 200 and 400, this will return True. This
        is **not** a check to see if the response code is ``200 OK``.
        """
        try:
            self.raise_for_status()
        except HTTPError:
            return False
        return True

    ...

    def raise_for_status(self):
        """Raises :class:`HTTPError`, if one occurred."""

        http_error_msg = ""
        if isinstance(self.reason, bytes):
            # We attempt to decode utf-8 first because some servers
            # choose to localize their reason strings. If the string
            # isn't utf-8, we fall back to iso-8859-1 for all other
            # encodings. (See PR #3538)
            try:
                reason = self.reason.decode("utf-8")
            except UnicodeDecodeError:
                reason = self.reason.decode("iso-8859-1")
        else:
            reason = self.reason

        if 400 <= self.status_code < 500:
            http_error_msg = (
                f"{self.status_code} Client Error: {reason} for url: {self.url}"
            )

        elif 500 <= self.status_code < 600:
            http_error_msg = (
                f"{self.status_code} Server Error: {reason} for url: {self.url}"
            )

        if http_error_msg:
            raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
```

So, what you are seeing is the expected behavior for the `Response` class - any status code of 400 or above will return False, while status codes < 400 return True.